# Prevent Knockout from caching loaded components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#component-lifecycle) says:

> Multiple component loaders may be consulted, until the first one
>   recognises the component name and supplies a viewmodel/template. This
>   process only takes place once per component type, since Knockout
>   caches the resulting definitions in memory.

The problem is that I don't want to load the template for component only once, I need to do it every time I add my component in a list. How can I prevent *Knockout* from loading components only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ko.components.clearCachedDefinition` function, which accepts a component name. This function clears the cached component definition.

As a first option, you can call this cache clearing inside your component viewmodel constructor for example, so that you apply this logic only for that component.

As a second option, if you need this logic globally, you can **try** to replace the original `ko.components.get` function like this. Note, that this is kind of a hack, and you should test it also with the minified build, as the behavior might differ.

```
ko.components.get = (function(fn) {
  return function(componentName, callback) {
    ko.components.clearCachedDefinition(componentName);
    fn(componentName, callback);
  };
})(ko.components.get);
```

Also note, that I didn't test this snippet in any ways, use this technique at your own risk.

Comment: I tried your solution, nothing happens. I add components to list, but still, jsavascript functions inside them don't execute.

Comment: Thanks, clearing cache in the component was exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear all registered components cache you can use this dirty hack:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ko.components._allRegisteredComponents).forEach(ko.components.clearCachedDefinition);
```