# Prevent Knockout from caching loaded components and templates

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Prevent Knockout from caching loaded components as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384873/prevent-knockout-from-caching-loaded-components/40385128#40385128)

[Prevent Knockout from caching loaded components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384873/prevent-knockout-from-caching-loaded-components/40385128#40385128)

the code

```
ko.components.get = (function(fn) {
  return function(componentName, callback) {
    ko.components.clearCachedDefinition(componentName);
    fn(componentName, callback);
  };
})(ko.components.get);
```

It clear only JS files but html templates not.

Can you help?

I tried to clear components, but it clears JS files only without html templates

Answer (score 0):

I changed the component files names as a temporary solution,
It works fine